# forbidden acces to direct page with nginx, accessible only via iframe

Tags: redirect, iframe, nginx

I want to avoid direct acces to a page via nginx.

I would like this page only accessible via an iframe which is on the same domain.

Is that possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can put various restrictions in place but they're pretty much all defeatable by an attacker that knows just a little of what they're doing -- this typically makes efforts to secure access as you describe a waste of time. If your intent is to inhibit data mining, you might be able to achieve your goal differently such as through rate limitation (not bandwidth, but intentional delays before retrieving data after the first few retrievals for a single user).

Answer (score 1):

When a page is loaded as content of an iframe the request's `Referer` is set to the containing page, so you can check whether the iframe content is actually loaded inside the iframe by checking the `Referer` header.

Of course that header can be spoofed pretty easily, but may be sufficient, and doesn't require reliance on eg Javascript running clientside.

Comment: It is just for esthetic. I will securise the two servers. Just, it is for an user who access directly the framed page see the normal page not found created bu the frontend website in a normal use.

Comment: @Michée I'm confused now, foes that mean that what I propose is usable or not?

Comment: Yes, what you proposed works greatly. Thanks. It is cleaner and more efficient than a javascipt solution.

Comment: But, of course, I won't base my security on that. It's just for design.

Comment: Ah ok, great :)  Good luck with your project

Comment: @Michée as a sidenote, I was wondering how someone can have 1 rep and 3 badges.  I think you may need to have a look at [the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to understand how this site works.

Comment: I just subscribed last week. It's only the beginning.